# Using Scrapy, how do I enter a blank string when no data is returned?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape a business directory. I have a couple of fields where I want to grab their Facebook and Twitter links. However, not everytime there is going to be a Facebook or Twitter link. Using the code I have now it just completely skips them.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

# TODO: Find a way to scrape even if there is nothing there
# TODO: Find a way to scrape any extra information

class BDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bd"
    start_urls = [
        'http://example.url',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        businesses = response.css('div.card-business')

        for business in businesses:
            relative_url = business.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)


            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'URL': absolute_url})


    def parse_page(self, response):
        url = response.meta.get('URL')

        # Parse the locations area of the page
        locations = response.css('address::text').extract()
        # Takes the City and Province and removes unicode and removes whitespace,
        # they are still together though.
        city_province = locations[1].replace(u'\xa0', u' ').strip()
        # List of all social links that the business has
        social = response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').extract()

        yield {
            'title' : response.css('h1.entry-title::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'description' : response.css('p.mb-double::text').extract_first(),
            'phone_number' : response.css('div.mb-double ul li::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'email' : response.css('div.mb-double ul li a::text').extract_first(),
            'address' : locations[0].strip(),
            'city' : city_province.split(' ', 1)[0].replace(',',''),
            'province' : city_province.split(' ', 1)[1].replace(',','').strip(),
            'zip_code' : locations[2].strip(),
            'website' : social[0],
            'facebook' : social[1],
            'twitter' : social[2],
            'linkedin' : social[3],
            'year' : response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'employees' : response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'key_contact' : response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'naics' : response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            'tags' : response.css('ul.biz-tags li a::text').extract(),
        }
```

I want to have it so that if they have those information then store it but if it doesn't then just leave a blank string. What's the best way I can do this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it skipping them because of an `IndexError` in the `social` list? If that's the case I'd try splitting that up into separate variables for facebook/twitter like this:

```
social = response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').extract()
try:
    facebook = social[0]
except IndexError:
    facebook = ''
```

Alternative method:

```
social = response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').extract()
social = dict(enumerate(social))
facebook = social.get(0, '')
twitter = social.get(1, '')
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, I am running into another issue. It seems like there are more than 4-5 variables that could be missing. Having a bunch of try/excepts is very messy. What's an easier way to go around this?

Comment: Yea, I understand that. I would probably extract it to a separate function. Or, if you want to limit it to just two lines per variable: `if len(social) >= 1: facebook = social[0]`

Comment: Here's yet another way you could do it. Assume we've extracted the response.css to `social` already. `social = dict(enumerate(social))` and then you could access the items by their index as you want by doing `social.get(0, '')`

Answer (score 1):

I will leave Cory Madden's answer up as it is a solution to my answer when getting the IndexError. However, I am realizing that **the code I was using was always going to lead me to error**. Meaning that using the `.extract()` function should only be used when you are **100% sure that there will be content there.** An example using the Business Directory: it's not always 100% that there is going to be a website, facebook or twitter. So instead I did this:

I took the absolute CSS selector (right click, copy > CSS Selector if you are using firefox) and pasted it in a `response.css('')` property. So my code will look like this:

```
yield {
    # ...code goes here
    facebook = response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first(default=''),
    # ...code goes here
}
```

Now instead of using the `try` and `except` methods, I found out that when using the `extract_first()` method, that you can pass in a parameter like `default='no data was found'`. In my case (where I wanted it to be blank), I used this:

`'facebook' : response.css(css_selector).extract_first(default='')`